# Number of solutions of the differential equation ${dy}\over {dx}$=$y^{1/3}$ $y(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The  given  differential equation  is ${dy}\over {dx}$=$y^{1/3}$, $y(0)=0$

I  got  the  solution $$y^{2/3}={{2}\over {3}}x$$
$$i.e. y^{2}={{8}\over {27}} x^{3}$$
$$i.e. y= \pm \sqrt{{{8}\over {27}}x^{3}}$$
  So  that  means this  equation  has  two  solutions.  Am  I  right?
  Actually  I  am  really  naive  at  differential  equations.

Comment: You missed the trivial solution $y(x) = 0$. You can easily check at which point your solution misses this case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since the function $F(x,y)=y(x)^{1 \over 3}$ is not uniformly Lipschitz-continuous in the second argument, the solution need not be unique.